# Attempting to route mobile, but a ValueError is raised

Tags: python, mobile, flask

I was working on a Flask site that needed to be mobile friendly and I found a nice code for mobile UA detection. just for tests, I created a route that would route my 404 page if mobile, or an index if not. My code is as follows:

```
# Main application file
# Created by James Parsons 2/23/15
from flask import *
from flask.ext.mobility import Mobility
from flask.ext.mobility.decorators import mobile_template
import re

def isMobile():
    browser = request.user_agent.browser
    version = request.user_agent.version and int(request.user_agent.version.split('.')[0])
    platform = request.user_agent.platform
    uas = request.user_agent.string

    if browser and version:
        if (browser == 'msie' and version < 9) \
        or (browser == 'firefox' and version < 4) \
        or (platform == 'android' and browser == 'safari' and version < 534) \
        or (platform == 'iphone' and browser == 'safari' and version < 7000) \
        or ((platform == 'macos' or platform == 'windows') and browser == 'safari' and not re.search('Mobile', uas) and version < 534) \
        or (re.search('iPad', uas) and browser == 'safari' and version < 7000) \
        or (platform == 'windows' and re.search('Windows Phone OS', uas)) \
        or (browser == 'opera') \
        or (re.search('BlackBerry', uas)):
            return True
    else:
        return False

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if isMobile():
        render_template("404.html")
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.errorhandler(404)
def error_404(err):
    return render_template("404.html"), 404

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

But when run with Chromes UA spoofing I get:

```
builtins.ValueError
ValueError: View function did not return a response

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to *return* the rendered template in the `ifMobile()` branch:

```
if isMobile():
    render_template("404.html")
    # No return, so the result is ignored
```

You end up returning `None` instead.

Add the `return` statement:

```
if isMobile():
    return render_template("404.html")
```

If you really wanted to return a HTTP 404 *Not Found* response, you also need to include a status code:

```
if isMobile():
    return render_template("404.html"), 404
```

Alternatively, use the [`abort()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.abort) to raise the appropriate exception and have Flask return the 404 view based on that:

```
from flask import abort

if isMobile():
    abort(404)
```